# R Console pumpkin hat android, swirl unable to load courses

Tags: android, r, swirl

Attempting to load swirl courses on android R Console premium.
Fails to load course with message  "Sorry, but I'm unable to fetch 'R Programming: The basics of programming in | R' right now. Are you sure you have an internet connection?"

Steps to recreate problem:

1. library (swirl)
2. swirl ()
3. Select option 1 "1: R Programming: The basics of programming in R"
4. Error msg "Sorry, but I'm unable to fetch ..."
5. Select option 2 "2: Send me to the course repository for manual installation."
6. error msg "> sh: 1: /usr/bin/firefox: not found"

Comment: Installed firefox to see if that solved it, but get same sequence of errors after firefox successful install